# change the format of string as bold in c# not accepting

Tags: c#, html, string, stringbuilder

I created the separate class and create variable like as follows,

```
public const string LOBUSERLOCKEDMESSAGE = "The Named LOB screen is locked by <b>[USER_ID]</b> and <b>[USER_NAME]</b>. Would you like to continue with Read only access?";
```

and my result is showing like

```
The Named LOB screen is locked by <b>xxx</b> and <b>yyyyy</b>. Would you like to continue with Read only access?
```

Why it is not getting bold if i gave correct syntax also? Kindly assist me on this

Comment: Because you are putting `html` markup in a `c#` string, and expecting magic to happen? Please provide more information. How and where are you displaying your result? For all I know, it could be in a console application...

Comment: then how will i get ? I google related to this. Some places they have used like this. so i taught this is correct approach

Comment: Get what? We don't even know if this is a desktop app, a console app, a web site etc...

Comment: i want to show this message in popup. i am getting full text from controller.

Comment: What popup? A WinForms MessageBox? A javascript alert? You need to be more specific, I don't have a working crystal ball.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to use HTML markup in C#.
Try this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287595%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: You can't know if OP is using a RichTextBox and link answers are not really acceptable.